# How to externalize the property in ehcache.xml

Tags: ehcache

I have an issue. The project is based on Maven. 
I have a property file, in which I have some variables. 
I want to call a variable say cacheName from inside ehcache.xml file.
I tried using ${name_of_variable}, but it did not work. Any suggestions pls?

Comment: Can you please clarify if you need that property to be replaced at build time or at runtime? The solutions to these two options would be totally different

Comment: And what is the Ehcache version?